# Idempotent direct summands of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

I know that if an ideal $I$ is a direct summand  of a ring $R$ then it is   an idempotent ideal, i.e. $I^2=I$.

> My question concerns the rings all of whose idempotent ideals are direct summands. Is there a well-known characterization for such rings?

Certainly, being a direct summand of $R$, any such ideal is generated by an idempotent element.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Noetherian rings have this property since idempotent ideals are generated by idempotents.

Comment: It seems you fell down on a question of Auslander; see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0308291.pdf), page 31.